# return 0 when count(*) is null

Tags: sql

I'm a beginner and I need your help.

I have two columns in a table:

1. A_VATNO and
2. the number of A_VATNO counted.

When no `A_VATNO` counted nothing exported as a row.

I need to get a zero for those `A_VATNO` missing on my list.

Below example, I don't get anything for A_VATNO = '123456789' AND A_ALARMTYPE = '40' because no records in the table `ALARMS`.

Example:

```
102030401  | 10 
987654321  | 45
```

Any solution to get this as a final result?

```
102030401  | 10
987654321  | 45
123456789  | 0
```

Thank you in advance!

```
 SELECT A_VATNO, COUNT(*) 
       FROM ALARMS 
   WHERE A_ALARMTYPE = '40' AND  A_VATNO IN

(
   '102030401',
'987654321',
'123456789'
   )
   AND DATE(A_ALARM_DATE) >= '2015-01-01' 
    AND DATE(A_ALARM_DATE) <= '2015-12-31'
      
   GROUP BY A_VATNO
     ;
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You need a derived table to use with an outer join.  Typical syntax is:

```
SELECT v.ATNO, COUNT(a.A_VATNO) 
FROM (SELECT '102030401' as VATNO UNION ALL
      SELECT '987654321' as VATNO UNION ALL
      SELECT '123456789' as VATNO
     ) v LEFT JOIN
     ALARMS a
     ON a.A_VATNO = v.vatno AND
        a.A_ALARMTYPE = '40' AND
        A_ALARM_DATE >= '2015-01-01' AND
        A_ALARM_DATE <= '2016-01-01'
GROUP BY v.VATNO ;
```